# Как получить путь картинки QPixmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

```
head_check = QPixmap('person\\age1\\Ольга\\head\\head.png')
print(head_check)
```

При принте получаю `<PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x03BF4730>` как мне получить путь до файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрел методы и свойства, и похоже никак – `QPixmap` не дает получить путь, переданный ему в конструктор.

Вам придется самому хранить путь и объект `QPixmap`, например в словаре:

```
pixmap_by_filename = dict()

# ...

file_name_head = 'person\\age1\\Ольга\\head\\head.png'
head_check = QPixmap(file_name_head)

pixmap_by_filename[head_check] = file_name_head

# ...

# Получили pixmap, ассоциированный с путем
pixmap = pixmap_by_filename[file_name_head]
```

---

#### Посмотрел исходники [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) и там есть этому подтверждение.

Вот так выглядит [конструктор](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-4), в который передается строка с путем к файлу [[1]](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/image/qpixmap.cpp#L279):

```
QPixmap::QPixmap(const QString& fileName, const char *format, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags)
    : QPaintDevice()
{
    init(0, 0, QPixmapData::PixmapType);
    if (!qt_pixmap_thread_test())
        return;

    load(fileName, format, flags);
}
```

Переменная `fileName` с путем передается в метод [load](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load) и там используется только для получения информации, но опять же без сохранения пути [[2]](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/image/qpixmap.cpp#L866):

```
bool QPixmap::load(const QString &fileName, const char *format, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags)
{
    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        return false;

    QFileInfo info(fileName);
    QString key = QLatin1Literal("qt_pixmap")
                  % info.absoluteFilePath()
                  % HexString<uint>(info.lastModified().toTime_t())
                  % HexString<quint64>(info.size())
                  % HexString<uint>(data ? data->pixelType() : QPixmapData::PixmapType);

    // Note: If no extension is provided, we try to match the
    // file against known plugin extensions
    if (!info.completeSuffix().isEmpty() && !info.exists())
        return false;

    if (QPixmapCache::find(key, *this))
        return true;

    QScopedPointer<QPixmapData> tmp(QPixmapData::create(0, 0, data ? data->type : QPixmapData::PixmapType));
    if (tmp->fromFile(fileName, format, flags)) {
        data = tmp.take();
        QPixmapCache::insert(key, *this);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

**PS.**

Подтверждение из официального форума `Qt`, что `QPixmap` не хранит путь:

- https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24523-Getting-image-file-from-QPixmap